How to fix "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples" Error?
If separating a dataset into train and test results in the following shapes for test dataset, why then one cannot compute the score of the prediction:
X_train_new.shape, y_train_new.shape = (420, 11), (420, 6)
X_test_new.shape, y_test_new.shape   = (207, 11), (207, 6)

pipe.fit(X_train_new, y_train_new)
pipe.score(X_test_new, y_test_new)   # problematic line


ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
samples: [207, 1]

Here is how pipe is defined:
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin

class ExponentialSmoothingWrapper(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        self.items = []

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.model_ = ExponentialSmoothing(y.reshape(-1))
        self.model_fit_ = self.model_.fit()
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.model_fit_.predict(start=None, end=None)

pipe = ExponentialSmoothingWrapper()


I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. from what I've read about holtwinters ExponentialSmoothing is a time series model. The fit method you created is flatting the y for the model (why?) and does nothing with the fit method of the model (X is useless there). same with the predict method, X is useless there. So basically your pipe is fitting nothing and the score method that uses the predict method for calculation, predicts nothing. What did you expected to see?
